# Obtener variable POST en php y AJAX en el mismo formulario, PHP SELF

Tags: php, html, ajax, canvas

Hola tengo este problema, tengo un canvas el cual me sirve como signature para documentos quee se envia al mismo formulario en donde se encuentra con `phpself`, pero al momento de hacer la conversión en ajax para mandarlo como *cadena de imagen*, no me trae nada la variable que recepciono por POST, en simples palabras. este es el código:

AJAX:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("firma");
  var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);

  $('#limpiar').on('click', function(){
      signaturePad.clear();
  });

  $('.enviado').on('click', function(){
    var dataURI = signaturePad.toDataURL("image/jpg")
    alert(dataURI);

    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: "cortesias_view.php",
        data: { firma: dataURI }
    }); 
  });
});
```

formulario de PHP}:

```
<form id="formu" name="formu" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
```

Recepcion de variables POST:

```
if (!empty($_POST['enviado'])) {
  $fecha = $_POST['theDate'];
  $folio = $_POST['folio'];
  $concepto = $_POST['concepto'];

  $clasificacion=$_POST['clasicacion'];
  $lugar=$_POST['lugar'];
  $firma=$_POST['firma'];
  echo 'firma: '.$firma;
  $solicitante = $_POST['solicitante'];
}
```

Boton submit:

```
 <td><input type="submit" name="enviado" class="enviado" id="enviado" value="GUARDAR" class="boton" /></td>
```

Canvas HTML:

```
<canvas id="firma" class="firma" name="firma" width="150" height="50" style="border: 2px solid #000;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

Estás utilizando AJAX, no estás haciendo un submit habitual. Por esta razón, **solo estás mandando** `firma` en el cuerpo de la petición. Por ende, `enviado` no existe en `$_POST` por lo que nunca entra en el condicional.

Debes enviar todos los valores del formulario. Ya que usas jQuery, usa [`serializeArray`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) para serializar el formulario a un array y enviarlo hacia el backend:

```
$('.enviado').on('click', function(){
  var dataURI = signaturePad.toDataURL("image/jpg");
  var data = $('#formu').serializeArray();

  $.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: "cortesias_view.php",
    data: {
      data: data,
      firma: dataURI
    }
  }); 
});
```

En el backend debes de parsear este array en forma de string a un array PHP. Esto lo haces mediante [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php):

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);

if ($data['enviado']) {
  $fecha = $data['theDate'];
  $folio = $data['folio'];
  $concepto = $data['concepto'];
  $clasificacion = $data['clasicacion'];
  $lugar = $data['lugar'];
  $solicitante = $data['solicitante'];
  $firma = $_POST['firma']; // aquí si usas $_POST
}
```

Comment: me dice que DATA no existe, ya lo puse global, el ajax solo me sirve para converción del canvas a base64, yo lo envió por URL a otro archivo y en ese archivo lo recupero por GET.

Comment: por eso lo recibo por POST por que ala URL le pongo la variable firma como concatenacion

Comment: Okay. A ver si te entiendo. El formulario lo envías de forma normal y la firma, mediante AJAX. Si son **dos peticiones distintas**, ¿por qué la tratas como si fuese una?

Comment: ya estuvo amigo, lo mande el codigo de imagen del canvas a  un input en hidden y ese input lo mando por post ! :) y lo codifico en un php aparte, gracias ! por su ayuda el ajax solo me sirvio como para poner ese dato en el input !